# How to create a path with arguments to a service

Tags: windows-services

I have tried the following:

```
sc create Test start=auto binpath= "C:\PATH\Example.exe Param1"
```

This work but when I try to start the service I get an error.
How do I add parameters to a service path?

Comment: Did you try putting path in quotes and Param1 in another quotes? Do you get error again?

Comment: Yes, but can u show me an example just in case im wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the path to the executable does not contain spaces, the command you're using should work.  (The problem might be with the code in your service instead.)

If the path to the exectuable *does* contain spaces, you have to escape the quote marks like this:

```
sc create MyService binpath= "\"c:\Program Files\My Service\myservice.exe\" Param1"
```